# Finding some countries in MapBox using Geocoding with autocomplete

Tags: mapbox

Is there a reason that MapBox doesn't zoom to France or United States when you type them in the search box?(fuuuuuuudge???!!!!)

https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/geocoding-auto/
(there is jsfiddle in the buttom of that page to test and change)

Answer (score 0):

Check the documentation for [L.mapbox.geocoderControl](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/api/v2.4.0/l-mapbox-geocodercontrol/#section-l-mapbox-geocodercontrol).  The demo code from Mapbox in the link you listed above has the intent of just showing you how to search `mapbox.places` with autocomplete on.

From the documentation you will need to set a callback using `geocoderControl.on(event, callback)` and `autoselect`.

Comment: in the search box, type "United" you'll see "United States", "United Kingdom" select either of them. what do get?

Comment: United States zooms to zoom=1.  United Kingdom zooms to zoom=4.  You'll need to set the view to zoom to the appropriate zoom level

Comment: but United States is not the whole world to make zoom equal to1

Comment: I recommend filing a defect with Mapbox.